# extending email validation in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having the below user registration form built in 6.0.1.250 version of ExtJs. I have an email field which accepts `.co`,`.com` till the four characters. I need to handle the recent `tlds` and want to override the email validation logic. I tried with the `validator` and applying the regex but the `regexText` is not supporting internationalisation. How to extend the `email` validation. I am using 6.0 version of extjs framework. Below is the code snippet for UserForm

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.users.NewUserForm', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
xtype: 'newuser',
title: '<span class="red-label">*</span>'+ l10n('new-user'),
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: '<span class="red-label">*</span>' + l10n('name'),
    name: 'username',
    maxLength: 80,
    allowBlank: false
}, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    inputType: 'password',
    fieldLabel: '<span class="red-label">*</span>' + l10n('password'),
    name: 'password1',
    vtype: 'password',
    initialPassField: 'password2',
    allowBlank: false,
    maskRe: /[^ ]/
}, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: '<span class="red-label">*</span>' + l10n('confirm-password'),
    vtype: 'password',
    inputType: 'password',
    name: 'password2',
    initialPassField: 'password1',
    allowBlank: false,
    maskRe: /[^ ]/
}, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: '<span class="red-label">*</span>' + l10n('e-mail-address'),
    name: 'emailAddress',
    vtype:'email',
    allowBlank: false
}, {
    xtype: 'textarea',
    fieldLabel: l10n('description'),
    name: 'userDescription'
  }]
});
```

Comment: What's the exact version of the framework you are using? I've tested all the way from version 6.0.0.540 to 6.5, and in all cases it accepts up to 5 chars for the domain name..

Comment: The version is 6.0.1.250

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override the email validation vtype like so:

```
Ext.define(null, {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.VTypes',
    email: function (value) {
        return /^(")?(?:[^\."\s])(?:(?:[\.])?(?:[\w\-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]))*\1@(\w[\-\w]*\.){1,5}([A-Za-z]){2,10}$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

I took the default email regex and changed so that it allows from 2 to 10 characters for the domain name.

**Edit**

If you use Sencha CMD, there is a special `overrides` folder where you should put your overrides. So you can create a file called `Vtypes.js`, place the code there, and after a `sencha app refresh` you will be fine. If you don't  - the override should be basically executed before you use the actual vtype. You might have a method called `applyOverrides` in your `Application.js`, and then call it first thing from your [launch](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.app.Application.html#method-launch) method.

Comment: Where do I need to put the above function in the code snippet I have shared. I am new to javascript

Comment: I do not use Sencha CMD. I do see the Application.js but there is not applyOverrides function there.

Comment: There isn't. You create one yourself, and call it from `launch`

Comment: what should be there inside the `applyOverrides` function. How will I be able to call the function you have provided from the `applyOverrides` function. Am I missing something here.

Comment: Yes, inside it you will have the `Ext.define..` code provided in the answer. Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/268j

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153872/discussion-between-zilcuanu-and-scebotari66).

Answer (score 0):

We can solve above using this simple approach:

```
{
   xtype: 'textfield',
   fieldLabel: '<span class="red-label">*</span>' + l10n('e-mail-address'),
   name: 'emailAddress',
   regex : /^(")?(?:[^\."])(?:(?:[\.])?(?:[\w\-!#$%&'*+\/=?\^_`{|}~]))*\1@(\w[\-\w]*\.){1,5}([A-Za-z]){2,6}$/,
   allowBlank: false
}
```