# I am new in EXT-JS ,Can any body help we which approch is better for custom validation of email?

Tags: extjs

I found a way to custom validate email:

```
{
   xtype: 'textfield',
   fieldLabel: '<span class="red-label">*</span>' + l10n('e-mail-address'),
   name: 'emailAddress',
   regex : /^(")?(?:[^\."])(?:(?:[\.])?(?:[\w\-!#$%&'*+\/=?\^_`{|}~]))*\1@(\w[\-\w]*\.){1,5}([A-Za-z]){2,6}$/,
   allowBlank: false
}
```

There was also [this approach, by scebotari66](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46089209/extending-email-validation-in-extjs):

```
Ext.define(null, {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.VTypes',
    email: function (value) {
        return /^(")?(?:[^\."\s])(?:(?:[\.])?(?:[\w\-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]))*\1@(\w[\-\w]*\.){1,5}([A-Za-z]){2,10}$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

Can any body help we which approach is better for custom validation of email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a custom email validator (Extjs already provides one) and you need use this validator in other textfields components, then you can create your own

```
// custom Vtype for vtype:'customEmail'
Ext.define('Override.form.field.VTypes', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.VTypes',
    customEmailRe: /^(")?(?:[^\."])(?:(?:[\.])?(?:[\w\-!#$%&'*+\/=?\^_`{|}~]))*\1@(\w[\-\w]*\.){1,5}([A-Za-z]){2,6}$/
    customEmailText: 'Not a valid email',
    customEmailMask: /[\w.\-@'"!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]/i,
});
```

You can use the native validator and combine with some other custom validation using `regex` config (classic toolkit) or `validators` config (modern toolkit).

Classic toolkit:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    vType: 'email',
    regex: /myCostomRegex/
}
```

Modern toolkit:

```
{
    xtype: 'emailfield',
    validators: /myCustomRegex/
}
```